# нужна помошь! д при нажатии на кнопку возникает вот эта ошибка: Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import axios from "axios";
import * as Constants from "../constants";

const styles = {
  buttonDeleted: {
    width: '30px',
    height: '30px',
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginTop: '25px'

  }
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 100
  }
});

export default function BasicTable() {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const queryResult = await axios.post(Constants.GRAPHQL_API, {
        query: Constants.GET_ATTRIBUTES_QUERY
      });
      const result = queryResult.data.data;
      setData({ attributes: result.attributes });
    };

    fetchData();
  });

  function removeData(id: any) {
    setData(data["attributes"].filter(row => id !== row.id))
  }

  return (

    <div>
      <form>
        <input />
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>

      {data ? (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>

                <TableCell>Id</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Constant Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>name_key</TableCell>
                <TableCell>name_value_singularName</TableCell>
                <TableCell>parsers_id</TableCell>
                <TableCell> parsers_inputs_key</TableCell>
                <TableCell> parsers_inputs_value_source</TableCell>
                <TableCell>parsers_inputs_value_attributeName</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>

              {

                data["attributes"].map(row => (

                  <TableRow key={row["id"]}>
                    {row.id ? <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell> : <TableCell>none</TableCell>}

                    {row.constantName ? <TableCell>{row.constantName}</TableCell> : <TableCell>none</TableCell>}

                    {row.name[0].key ? <TableCell>{row.name[0].key}</TableCell> : <TableCell>none</TableCell>}

                    {row.name[0].value.singularName ? <TableCell>{row.name[0].value.singularName}</TableCell> : <TableCell>none</TableCell>}

                    {row.parsers[0] ? <TableCell>{row.parsers[0].id}</TableCell> : <TableCell>none</TableCell>}

                    {row.parsers[0] ? <TableCell>{row.parsers[0].inputs[0].key}</TableCell> : <TableCell>none</TableCell>}

                    {row.parsers[0] ? <TableCell>{row.parsers[0].inputs[0].value[0].source}</TableCell> : <TableCell>none</TableCell>}

                    {row.parsers[0] ? <TableCell>{row.parsers[0].inputs[0].value[0].attributeName}</TableCell> : <TableCell>none</TableCell>}

                    <button onClick={() => removeData(row.id)} style={styles.buttonDeleted}>&times;</button>
                  </TableRow>

                ))
              }


            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      ) : <h1>Loading...</h1>}

    </div>

  );
}
```

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку удаления строки? Можете добавить образец данных `data.attributes` ?

Comment: {
    "data": {
      "attributes": [
        {
          "id": "2649e8b4-33df-4dbc-9d4f-0ee39a3f40dd",
          "constantName": null,                          (остальные строчки выглядят примерно также)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была здесь:

```
 function removeData(id: any) {
   setData(data["attributes"].filter(row => id !== row.id))
 }
```

Данный код изменяеят структуру стейта. Правильно написать:

```
 function removeData(id) {
    setData({
      ...data,
      attributes: data.attributes.filter((row) => id !== row.id),
    });
  }
```

Также в рендере я бы написал:

```
return data && data.attributes ? (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
       ...
```

Вообщем набросал рабочий пример, у меня получилось так:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const styles = {
  buttonDeleted: {
    width: "30px",
    height: "30px",
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    marginTop: "25px",
  },
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    minWidth: 100,
  },
});

export default function BasicTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fakeData = {
      attributes: [
        { id: "1", constantName: "constantName1", name: "name1" },
        { id: "2", constantName: "constantName2", name: "name2" },
        { id: "3", constantName: "constantName3", name: "name3" },
        { id: "4", constantName: "constantName4", name: "name4" },
      ],
    };

    setData(fakeData);
  }, []);

  function removeData(id) {
    setData({
      ...data,
      attributes: data.attributes.filter((row) => id !== row.id),
    });
  }      

  return data && data.attributes ? (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <TableContainer className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Id</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Constant Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell>name_key</TableCell>
            <TableCell>name_value_singularName</TableCell>
            <TableCell>parsers_id</TableCell>
            <TableCell> parsers_inputs_key</TableCell>
            <TableCell> parsers_inputs_value_source</TableCell>
            <TableCell>parsers_inputs_value_attributeName</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.attributes.map(({ id, constantName, name }) => (
            <TableRow key={id}>
              <TableCell>{id ? id : "none"}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{constantName ? constantName : "none"}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{name ? name : "none"}</TableCell>
              <button
                onClick={() => removeData(id)}
                style={styles.buttonDeleted}
              >
                &times;
              </button>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </TableContainer>
    </TableContainer>
  ) : (
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: это классное решение. Спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста, я рад что помог. Отметь пожалуйста ответ как правильный если не сложно. Лайк поставить наверное не получится.